# Как сделать размытие предыдущего блока, когда размер нового блока занимает больше, чем полэкрана в высоту?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Занимаюсь версткой сайта и получил такое ТЗ. Все пытался это реализовать, но не хватает знаний, не могу найти подобные ссылки. Буду очень благодарен, если прикрепите ссылку на решение или покажите, как сделать на JS.

---

ТЗ:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: эти секции добавляются динамически? зачем нужно делать именно с js?

Comment: Нет, не динамически, новый блок, в плане, появляющегося на экране

Comment: создай класс с размытием и ставь его на такие блоки. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur()

Comment: Да, я его использую через JS, но мне же нужно по мере ухода блока за границы верхней части экрана блюрить его

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API то, что Вам надо

Comment: Ого, спасибо, гляну)

Comment: А как сделать сразу такое на нескольких блоках?